# Multiple nested flex: Cannot restrict height

Tags: css, flexbox

Look at this Code (Full page):

```css
html {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* section */
.theme-paragraph-section-subtitle {
  font-family: "Khand";
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 0.67;
  color: #ffb400;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-title {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.theme-paragraph-section {
  height: calc(100vh - 7.5rem);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.theme-paragraph-section:before,
.theme-paragraph-section:after {
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(45rem / 2);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-content {
  padding: 6.3rem 0rem 3rem;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  min-width: 75rem;
  max-width: 120rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-header,
.theme-paragraph-section-body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  /* -webkit-box-align: stretch; */
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-content-container {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 100%;
  /* display: -webkit-box; */
  /* display: flex; */
  height: 100%;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-subtitle {
  margin: 0;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-title {
  margin: 0;
  width: 80rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-first,
.theme-paragraph-section-next {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: block;
  color: #ffb400;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear;
  transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-first:hover,
.theme-paragraph-section-first:focus,
.theme-paragraph-section-first:active,
.theme-paragraph-section-next:hover,
.theme-paragraph-section-next:focus,
.theme-paragraph-section-next:active {
  color: #114f40;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-first {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

/* body --------------------------------------------------------- */
.theme-paragraph-body p.intro {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.18;
  color: #0c6158;
}

.theme-paragraph-body p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.33;
  color: #000000;
}

.theme-paragraph-body li,
.theme-paragraph-body dd {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.18;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.theme-paragraph-body {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: 19rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 3rem);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: auto;
}

.theme-paragraph-body .theme-field-body {
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5rem 4rem 5rem 5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.theme-paragraph-body .theme-field-body-content {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.theme-paragraph-body p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.theme-paragraph-body ul,
.theme-paragraph-body ol,
.theme-paragraph-body dl {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3.6rem 0 0 2.7rem;
}

.theme-paragraph-body ul:first-child,
.theme-paragraph-body ol:first-child,
.theme-paragraph-body dl:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.theme-paragraph-body li,
.theme-paragraph-body dd {
  margin: 1.18rem 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  min-height: 3.6rem;
  position: relative;
}

.theme-paragraph-body ul li li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

#paragraph-207 .theme-paragraph-section-next {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme-paragraph-section" id="paragraph-15">
  <div class="theme-paragraph-section-content">
    <div class="theme-paragraph-section-header">
      <h3 class="theme-paragraph-section-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      <h2 class="theme-paragraph-section-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="theme-paragraph-section-body">

      <div class="theme-paragraph-section-content-container type-paragraph_body ">

        <div class="theme-paragraph-body" id="paragraph-123">

          <div class="theme-field-body ss-container">
            <div class="theme-field-body-content">
              <p class="intro">The text inside this box is cropped at the end of the box. The box should be scrollable, but I can't restrict the height of the box to the height of the container.</p>

              <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, alias ab. Molestiae consectetur quae veniam?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero ut, nisi perferendis placeat et reiciendis, quam vel aliquid, quibusdam fugiat iure minus enim possimus amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate sapiente velit quibusdam rerum? Tempore, sequi assumenda neque consequatur voluptate vero rerum eveniet?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam officia odio ullam nemo fugit impedit optio natus? Laborum temporibus non sit qui vero nisi, necessitatibus consequuntur eum iusto velit accusamus eos perferendis tenetur corrupti nemo magni veniam harum quisquam error.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, nisi.:
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit;</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing;</li>
                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sapiente architecto, autem debitis porro ea fugiat ipsa. Ullam, et possimus.</li>
              </ul>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eius quaerat quae suscipit, fugiat totam quasi reiciendis maiores aspernatur nihil architecto natus expedita dolorum dolorem pariatur repellendus et ut officia quia rerum, cupiditate ratione beatae! Atque temporibus minus ducimus optio?</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, dolores labore. Deserunt autem vero impedit sapiente quibusdam, modi ratione eaque officia. Molestiae soluta maxime impedit perferendis earum iusto corporis dolores, quibusdam deleniti illum veniam doloribus ab architecto id nesciunt voluptatum.</p>
              <p>Quos aliquam eaque, vitae explicabo quibusdam commodi a ipsum molestiae cupiditate, temporibus quis expedita, assumenda in aspernatur accusamus consectetur praesentium aliquid tenetur voluptas animi autem repellendus? Est aspernatur, repellendus quae, nostrum delectus dolorem quo, beatae ad magnam obcaecati repellat vel?</p>
              <p>Itaque voluptas eum earum esse. Eligendi maiores odio, omnis dicta obcaecati eius nisi, aspernatur unde iste porro at nulla vitae placeat repudiandae sapiente ducimus tempora pariatur perferendis. Voluptates tempore nostrum, repudiandae ipsa incidunt quaerat architecto, temporibus delectus cum nesciunt voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

It's a stripped down example of some real life code. The structure must be that complex, because there are other contents, which are not shown in the example.

If you examince `.theme-paragraph-section-body` element: It has thise style

```css
.theme-paragraph-section-body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So it is a horizontal flex container. And it has restricted height because of the parent elements. IRL it should have two children. But I left the second one out for simplicity. It's not necessary to demonstrate the issue. But be aware, that this flex container is necessarily `flex-direction: row`.

The direct child `.theme-paragraph-section-content-container` should be a flex item, which should have a max-height of 100% of the parent flex container. But I can't make it obey the `max-height`rule.

The issue is, that the text inside the white box is cropped at the end. I want to make it scroll inside the box, but I can't get it to work.

Computed box of `.theme-paragraph-section-body`

[image]

Computed box of `.theme-paragraph-section-content-container`

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: I don't really get what you want to achieve :/ What is the expected result?

Comment: @johannchopin I added a paragraph to the end

Comment: @johannchopin And some demonstration screenshots

Comment: @Awais You seem to be correct. Do you have any explanation for that? Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @yunzen no the problem is not with max-height so i del my comment the issue is with inner structure properties may be columns of flex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a flex-shrink that should be set to 1, some overlow needed and some directions changed from row to column.

```
.theme-paragraph-section-body {
  flex-direction: column; /* updated */
}

.theme-paragraph-section-content-container {
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* you need flex-shrink=1 */
  overflow: auto; /* added this (or min-height:0) */
  display:flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: column; /* added this */
}

.theme-paragraph-body {
  min-height: 0; /* added (or overflow:auto) */
}
```

Check comments in the below code:

```css
html {
  font-family: Montserrat, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, orange, purple);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

/* section */
.theme-paragraph-section-subtitle {
  font-family: "Khand";
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 0.67;
  color: #ffb400;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-title {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.theme-paragraph-section {
  height: calc(100vh - 7.5rem);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.theme-paragraph-section:before,
.theme-paragraph-section:after {
  content: "";
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: calc(45rem / 2);
  pointer-events: none;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-content {
  padding: 6.3rem 0rem 3rem;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  min-width: 75rem;
  max-width: 120rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-header,
.theme-paragraph-section-body {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  /* -webkit-box-align: stretch; */
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
          align-items: stretch;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  flex-direction: column; /* updated */
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-content-container {
  flex: 0 1 100%; /* you need flex-shrink=1 */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;    
  overflow: auto; /* added this */
  align-self: flex-start;    
  display:flex; /* added */
  flex-direction: column; /* added this */
}

.theme-paragraph-section-subtitle {
  margin: 0;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-title {
  margin: 0;
  width: 80rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-first,
.theme-paragraph-section-next {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  display: block;
  color: #ffb400;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.3s linear;
  transition: color 0.3s linear;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-first:hover,
.theme-paragraph-section-first:focus,
.theme-paragraph-section-first:active,
.theme-paragraph-section-next:hover,
.theme-paragraph-section-next:focus,
.theme-paragraph-section-next:active {
  color: #114f40;
}

.theme-paragraph-section-first {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
  transform: scaleY(-1);
}

/* body --------------------------------------------------------- */
.theme-paragraph-body p.intro {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.18;
  color: #0c6158;
}

.theme-paragraph-body p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.33;
  color: #000000;
}

.theme-paragraph-body li,
.theme-paragraph-body dd {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.18;
  color: #4a4a4a;
}

.theme-paragraph-body {
  margin-top: 3rem;
  margin-left: 19rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(100% - 3rem);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: auto;
  min-height: 0; /* added */
}

.theme-paragraph-body .theme-field-body {
  flex-basis: auto;
  margin: 5rem 4rem 5rem 5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-scroll-chaining: none;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.theme-paragraph-body .theme-field-body-content {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.theme-paragraph-body p:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.theme-paragraph-body ul,
.theme-paragraph-body ol,
.theme-paragraph-body dl {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 3.6rem 0 0 2.7rem;
}

.theme-paragraph-body ul:first-child,
.theme-paragraph-body ol:first-child,
.theme-paragraph-body dl:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.theme-paragraph-body li,
.theme-paragraph-body dd {
  margin: 1.18rem 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  list-style-position: outside;
  min-height: 3.6rem;
  position: relative;
}

.theme-paragraph-body ul li li {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

#paragraph-207 .theme-paragraph-section-next {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="theme-paragraph-section" id="paragraph-15">
  <div class="theme-paragraph-section-content">
    <div class="theme-paragraph-section-header">
      <h3 class="theme-paragraph-section-subtitle">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h3>
      <h2 class="theme-paragraph-section-title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="theme-paragraph-section-body">

      <div class="theme-paragraph-section-content-container type-paragraph_body ">

        <div class="theme-paragraph-body" id="paragraph-123">

          <div class="theme-field-body ss-container">
            <div class="theme-field-body-content">
              <p class="intro">The text inside this box is cropped at the end of the box. The box should be scrollable, but I can't restrict the height of the box to the height of the container.</p>

              <ul>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, alias ab. Molestiae consectetur quae veniam?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vero ut, nisi perferendis placeat et reiciendis, quam vel aliquid, quibusdam fugiat iure minus enim possimus amet.</li>
                <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate sapiente velit quibusdam rerum? Tempore, sequi assumenda neque consequatur voluptate vero rerum eveniet?</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam officia odio ullam nemo fugit impedit optio natus? Laborum temporibus non sit qui vero nisi, necessitatibus consequuntur eum iusto velit accusamus eos perferendis tenetur corrupti nemo magni veniam harum quisquam error.</li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, nisi.:
                  <ul>
                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit;</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing;</li>
                    <li>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</li>
                    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquid sapiente architecto, autem debitis porro ea fugiat ipsa. Ullam, et possimus.</li>
              </ul>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Mollitia eius quaerat quae suscipit, fugiat totam quasi reiciendis maiores aspernatur nihil architecto natus expedita dolorum dolorem pariatur repellendus et ut officia quia rerum, cupiditate ratione beatae! Atque temporibus minus ducimus optio?</p>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed, dolores labore. Deserunt autem vero impedit sapiente quibusdam, modi ratione eaque officia. Molestiae soluta maxime impedit perferendis earum iusto corporis dolores, quibusdam deleniti illum veniam doloribus ab architecto id nesciunt voluptatum.</p>
              <p>Quos aliquam eaque, vitae explicabo quibusdam commodi a ipsum molestiae cupiditate, temporibus quis expedita, assumenda in aspernatur accusamus consectetur praesentium aliquid tenetur voluptas animi autem repellendus? Est aspernatur, repellendus quae, nostrum delectus dolorem quo, beatae ad magnam obcaecati repellat vel?</p>
              <p>Itaque voluptas eum earum esse. Eligendi maiores odio, omnis dicta obcaecati eius nisi, aspernatur unde iste porro at nulla vitae placeat repudiandae sapiente ducimus tempora pariatur perferendis. Voluptates tempore nostrum, repudiandae ipsa incidunt quaerat architecto, temporibus delectus cum nesciunt voluptatum!</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```